# 'Contains' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'

Tags: vb.net

I want to stop people sending us messages including the word "telegram".

I have a very old script in VB that uses sendmail. It has always worked fine. Now I am trying to add this:

```
Sub CheckTelegram()
    'check for Telegram
    If messagetext.Contains("telegram") Then
        messagetext.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    Else
```

But I receive an error:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'Contains' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

Can I not use `.Contains()` this way? I was expecting the border to go red if "telegram" was within the text box.

Answer (score 2):

the `TextBox` class itself is not a text. You must access the `Text` property which is of type `String`:

```vb
If messagetext.Text.Contains("telegram") Then
'              ^^^^
```

Because `Contains` is a method of the `String` class, not a method of the `TextBox` class.

---

Note that older VB versions (VB 6.0, VBA) had the concept of default properties. You could effectively call `s = Me!TextBox1` and if `s` was typed as `String`, VB was smart enough to see that a `TextBox` could not be assigned to `s` and the `Text` or `Value` property was automatically retrieved.

VB.NET has a stronger typing and also wants you to do more things explicitly (especially if you have `Option Strict On`, what I urge you to do). This is better for the understanding of the code and leads to less programing errors. E.g., if you have a declaration `Dim obj As Object` then what should `obj = Me!TextBox1` do? Assign the `TextBox` or `TextBox.Text`? Such an automatism can be very confusing.

Comment: Note that default properties still exist in .NET.  I'm not sure what limitations they may have.

Comment: Yes, but they have a different meaning. They are what is called an "indexer" in C# and require a parameter used as index. [Default property in VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property). [Default property in VBA](https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/694992-how-declare-default-property-class-module).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this - I think that the fact the box property was called messagetext confused me.

Comment: Yeah, naming is a crucial part in software design. I've already caught myself not understanding my own code anymore. That was a clear sign to apply the [Boy Scout Rule](https://www.stepsize.com/blog/how-to-be-an-effective-boy-girl-scout-engineer) and to make a few rename-refactorings.